# Effect of mismatches on string matching finite automata

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, search-algorithms, strings, matching

I am contemplating a string matching FA algorithm (not KMP). The complexity of its transition function calculation ie the preprocessing is m(length of pattern )* (the language of the FA) . What effect would greater or fewer mismatches have on this algorithm, for example in a case where all elements in the pattern are the same, such as [ccccc].

Comment: What is "m"?  How do you mesure "(the language of the FA) "? You should use Landau (big O) notation. What matching algorithm are youn contemplating?

Comment: Can you define more precisely what you call a mismatch.